# Indicates people's initials and skype user, where the skype user starts with a letter and ends with a number;

Tags: awk

```
awk -F ';' '$5 ~ /^[a-zA-Z]/ {print $1, $5}' users.txt

- prints skype users starting with a-z or A-Z


awk -F ';' '$5 ~ /[0-9]$/ {print $1, $5}' users.txt

- prints the skype users that finish with numbers
```

so my question is, i want to put it together in one function..
but when i do this :

```
awk -F ';' '$5 ~ /^[a-zA-Z] && [0-9]$/ {print $1, $5}' users.txt
or this:
awk -F ';' '$5 ~ /^[a-zA-Z]||[0-9]$/ {print $1, $5}' users.txt
```

this not return what i pretend..
individual yes, but together no..

i want to print all de skype users that begin with a-zA-Z and finish with numbers 0-9
like diz :

live:joaoeu0
live:pedroada02

anyone can help me put together?

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F ';' '{if($5 ~ /^[a-zA-Z]/ && $5 ~/[0-9]$/) print $1, $5}' users.txt
```

Comment: Although this code might solve the problem, a good answer should also explain what it does and how it helps.

Answer (score 0):

For or

```
awk -F ';' '$5 ~ /^[a-zA-Z]|[0-9]$/ {print $1, $5}' users.txt
```

For AND

```
awk -F ';' '$5 ~ /^[a-zA-Z].*[0-9]$/ {print $1, $5}' users.txt
```

Comment: yeye, i already do this with a cicle if , but this is really nice too, thx bro!!